# Application (valhalla-server) not running (or accessible) )when exposed through clusterIP or NodePort service

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, project-valhalla

I have created a pod to deploy valhalla-server, yaml below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: valahalla-pod
  labels:
    app: valahalla-app-pod  # Updated label name
spec:
  containers:
  - name: docker-valahalla
    image: ghcr.io/gis-ops/docker-valhalla/valhalla
    env:
      - name: tile_urls
        value: "https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/andorra-latest.osm.pbf ghcr.io/gis-ops/docker-valhalla/valhalla:latest"
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8002
    volumeMounts:
    - name: my-local-folder
      mountPath: /custom_files
  volumes:
  - name: my-local-folder
    hostPath:
      path: /home/ubuntu/custom_files
```

When I exec into this pod, I am able to access the valhalla server on localhost on port 8002. But I have created a service for the pod, yaml below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: valahalla-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: valahalla-app-pod 
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80  # Port exposed by the service
      targetPort: 8002 
  type: NodePort
```

I am not able to access my application through this! It gives output when I curl by going into the pod but not when I try to access it from outisde.

I am using EKS on AWS for this.

I was using deployment before, I've tried using pod instead and changed service from clusterIP to NodePort.

Comment: Can it be that your app is listening just on localhost:8002 (127.0.0.1:8002) instead of all interfaces (0:8002) ?